# SQL use selected values in where statement

Tags: sql, variables, select, where-clause

I use 2 SQL commands. First is to get some reference values, and the second is to filter with it. The results of the first command are used as :FINISH_TIME and :START_TIME in the second.

```
select FINISHED, STARTED from table
   where id = :ID

select * from table
where (FINISHED <= :FINISH_TIME
and
FINISHED >= :START_TIME)
or
(STARTED <= :FINISH_TIME
and
STARTED >= :START_TIME)
or
(STARTED <= :START_TIME
and
FINISHED >= :FINISH_TIME
)
```

I would like to combine these two commands so I dont have to manually copy the reference values to the second command.

I found a solution like this:

```
FINISHED <= (select FINISHED from table where id = :ID)
```

but this is redundant. Is there a better way to do this, like use the searched value as a variable?

thanks for the help!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Please tag your question properly.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, so we can see what you really want to accomplish.

Comment: The two query are performed on diffrent tables  or the table is the same for both the query ?

Comment: if both tables are same then last two conditions of second query makes whole condition true. Doesn't make any sense of total conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably get the records with an overlapping time range with just one select.

```sql
select t.*
from yourtable t
inner join (
  select id, finished, started 
  from yourtable 
  where id = :id
  ) s
on (    t.finished >= s.started
    and t.started <= s.finished
    and t.started <= t.finished 
    --and t.id <> s.id
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a CTE

```
with TQ as
(
select FINISHED, STARTED from table
   where id = :ID
)

select *
from Table1 T1
inner join TQ
  on ((T1.FINISHED <= TQ.FINISHED
       and T1.FINISHED >= TQ.STARTED)
  or ...
```